# Find Pi number using Turing Machine

Tags: pi, turing-machines

What is the most convenient and fast way to find first $n$ binary digits of $\pi$ using Turing Machine?

Comment: Turing machines in the strictest sense don't exist, so using them is very inconvenient.

Comment: Can you program your Turing machine to type "first n bits of pi" into Google?

Comment: And even if they existed, it wouldn't be fast ...